# I have confusion understanding why Zero Vector space has dimension zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra, linear-independence

Here's what I understand from  Basis.

Basis: it's set of linearly independent vectors which can span the vector space.

**Basis for Zero vector space:**

***case 1:*** when { 0 } , it's singleton set , since there's none in it to compare with to check linear independecy hence it can be considered as basis and also it can span it.

( i.e 0 = c . 0 , where c is any constant )

So, the basis has 1 vector, so dimension will be 1.

***case 2:*** { any vector K } again it's singleton set , since there's none in it to compare with to check linear independecy hence it can be considered as basis and also it can span it.

( i.e 0 = 0. K (the vector K) )

Again, the basis has 1 vector, so dimension will be 1.

Comment: *Short answer: Because its basis is the empty set $\emptyset$.* See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: Personally, I consider the zero vector space having dimension zero to be a convention. To actually make it follow from definition, you need to be more careful in how you define basis.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I appreciate your response. can you also please answer where I am wrong in my argument. Thanks

Comment: You are wrong because of what egreg says in his answer. You forgot case $3$, the only one which works (namely *What's the largest linearly independent set in $\{\mathbf{0}\}$? The only subsets in it are the empty set and the whole set.*)

Comment: Bases are linearly independent. So, in order for $\{\vec{0}\}$ to be a basis, we must have $c \vec{0} = \vec{0} \implies c = 0$. But this is not true, for example if $c = 1$.